# Unite in one conditional statements IF different conditional statements IF (javaScript)

Tags: javascript

```
  var message;    
        if ( $('#one').length == 1 ){
           message = "101";
        }
        if ( $('#two').length == 2 ){ 
           message = "102";
        }
        if ( $('#third').length == 3 ){
           message = "103";
        }
    console.log(message);
```

How I can do unite all IF in one IF use operator ( || or another) and depending on the condition show different message?
    I tried do it but was unfortunate.
    Thank you for your advance.

Comment: Can you include HTML at Question?

Comment: I apologize the question was incorrect I corrected it

Comment: Are you saying that there could be three elements on the page with the ID `three`? I think you're running into the trap of asking about your solution instead of describing the actual problem.

Comment: The edited Question is not fully "corrected". The Question is entirely different now, though still has the same issue of the apparent duplicate `id` at different elements at HTML. Again, can you include the HTML and full JavaScript used at the text of the Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can simply do

```
var message = "10"+$('#one').length;
console.log(message);
```

note that have a a condition for `0` length. However why you have multiple elements with same id? you mean class ?

Comment: I apologize the question was incorrect I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

The resulting `.length` of using selector `"#one"` should always be either `0` or `1` as `id` of element in `document` should be unique, not duplicated at another element.

If there are multiple elements having `id` `"one"` substitute `class` for `id` at the elements at HTML and use selector `".one"`.

Comment: I apologize the question was incorrect I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

The question has changed, and to be honest is making less sense than before.

What I'll do is assume that you want to select all three elements, and configure a message based on how many actual elements were found. I'll use my second example from below to show how with IDs, though classes are nicer.

```
var msgs = {
  1: "101",
  2: "102",
  3: "103",
}

var message = msgs[$("#one,#two,#three").length] || "Unknown";
```

So now it will try to select all three, and will give a message based on how many were actually found.

This again does not assume that the actual situation is as simple as merely appending the length to a string.

---

***original answer***

I'm not going to make the assumption that there's always going to be such a neat paring between the `.length` and the message.

So a more general solution would be to use a `switch` statement.

```
var message;    
switch ( $('#one').length ) {
  case 1: message = "101"; break;
  case 2: message = "102"; break;
  case 3: message = "103"; break;
  default: message = "Unknown";
}
console.log(message);
```

---

A `switch` is not the only way. You could also create an object that associates a number with a message.

```
var msgs = {
  1: "101",
  2: "102",
  3: "103",
}

var message = msgs[$("#one").length] || "Unknown";
```

---

Note that jQuery will only return one element for an ID selector, though `querySelectorAll` could return multiple, though duplicate IDs isn't good.

Comment: I apologize the question was incorrect I corrected it